# how to debug the HTML markup in aspx file?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

how to debug the HTML markup in aspx file? There is a cart button in my page and I have a Jquery snippet called when the button is clicked. How do I debug  the script?

Comment: F12 Developer Tools would be a better debugging tool for you, what about this issue now?

Answer (score 2):

Press F12 in your browser.  Look for a "console" tab.  Works in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge.
  Client side debugging is more effectively done in a browser.